# python regex how to give space after specific string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

my code:

```
text = '12\nx\n$79.17\n8\nx\n$118.75\n6\nx\n$158.33\n4\nx\n$237.50'

re.sub(r'(\n)', '', text)
>>>12x$79.178x$118.756x$158.334x$237.50
```

my expected result will be:

```
 <br> 12x$79.17 <br> 8x$118.75 <br> 6x$158.33 <br> 4x$237.50 <br>
```

I want to add `<br>` tag before every whole number.

**update1:**

```
text = short_des.replace('\n',' ')
  >>>'12 x $79.17 8 x $118.75 6 x $158.33 4 x $237.50'
```

now I want to add `<br>` before every whole number.

Comment: Your text is invalid python, please make sure that the posted code runs **and gives you the expected output**

Comment: Why regex? `text = text.replace('\n', ' <br> ')`

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew becasue I want to add `<br>` on specific location.  if  `text = text.replace('\n', ' <br> ') ` then result will be `'12 <br> x <br> $79.17 <br> 8 <br> x <br> $118.75 <br> 6 <br> x <br> $158.33 <br> 4 <br> x <br> $237.50'` but my expected result will be look like this `12x$79.17 <br> 8x$118.75 <br> 6x$158.33 <br> 4x$237.50 <br>`

Comment: @mozway I added my expected output

Comment: So as well as adding the `<br>` before whole numbers you also want to remove all other `\n`. Yes?

Comment: MikeM yes sir exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be to use `re.sub` with a dictionary to map the replacements:

```
text = '12\nx\n$79.17\n8\nx\n$118.75\n6\nx\n$158.33\n4\nx\n$237.50'

repl = {'\nx\n': 'x', '\n': ' <br> '}

import re
out = re.sub(r'(\nx\n|\n)', lambda m: repl.get(m.group()), text)
```

Output:

```
'12x$79.17 <br> 8x$118.75 <br> 6x$158.33 <br> 4x$237.50'
```

*NB. As `\n` is a substring of `\nx\n` it must come after in the regex to match second.*

Comment: @Thanks for your help. Can you please explain `lambda m: repl.get(m.group())`

Comment: Seemed self explanatory ;) each key is a possible match and the corresponding value is used as replacement. For instance, if `\nx\n' is found, it is replaced by `x`